# Getting an issue in applying margin on the runtime using angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an li element in which we are calling a method **SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset** like this:

```
<li class="holder-white title-holder" data-ng-style="{{SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset()}}">
 ...
</li>
```

and from our javascript controller it being called like this:

```
function SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset() {

    var isPPMJob = localStorage.getItem("IsPPMJob").toUpperCase();

    var shiftingAsset = $scope.addClassForShiftingAsset;

    if (isPPMJob == "FALSE") {

        // it is working fine here. Margin is being applied correctly. 
        return { "margin-right": "50px" };
    }
    else if (isPPMJob == "TRUE") {
        if (shiftingAsset.toUpperCase() == "TRUE")
        {
            //it is not working fine on this line. Margin is not being applied.
            return { "margin-right": "50px" };
        }
        else {
            return { "padding-right:": "15px" };
        }
    }
}
```

So it is working fine in the first **if (isPPMJob == "FALSE")** but in else if where we are checking **shiftingAsset.toUpperCase() == "TRUE"** that margin is not being applied.

Tried alerts on all conditions they are showing fine but margins are causing problems.

Comment: Have you done a console.log or a breakpoint to test whether you're actually hitting the line of code that applies the margin?

Comment: Yes @JacobStamm I have added an alert just before the line that is applying the margin and I have also inspected the element and it was showing data-ng-style="{"margin-right":"50px"}" but on the view nothing was changed !!!

Comment: Since both the first and second returns return the exact same value, the only possible thing that's different between those two conditions is the value of `$scope.addClassForShiftingAsset`. Not a solution, but it is somewhere to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for that problem. The problem was with HTML code we were using data-ng-style like this

```
data-ng-style="{{SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset()}}"
```

instead of this we have to use it like

```
data-ng-style="{'margin-right': SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset()}"
```

Then in JS controller just return value of margin i.e. "10px" , "50px",etc

function SiteAssetStyleForShiftedAsset() {

```
    var isPPMJob = localStorage.getItem("IsPPMJob").toUpperCase();

    var shiftingAsset = $scope.addClassForShiftingAsset;

    if (shiftingAsset == "false"){
                //alert("abc");
         return "10px";
                //return { "padding-right:": "15px" };
    }
    else{
        return "50px";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the first `return { "margin-right": "50px" }` where your code snippet says it works fine. I suspect it wasn't actually working then.

Comment: @Taimoor you are right. this is just another way of doing it and if it is working like this then we can go with it.